# How to set wildcard option in CI's ->like()

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I Need to format my SQL with CI like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM (`items`)
WHERE `name`  LIKE '%Spinner%60%'
ORDER BY `name` asc
```

Here's my db query

```
$search = str_replace(" ","%",$search);

$this->db->from('items');
$this->db->like('name', $search);
$this->db->order_by("name", "asc");
```

But I get this as,

```
SELECT *
FROM (`items`)
WHERE `name`  LIKE '%Spinner\%60%'
ORDER BY `name` asc
```

How can I prevent the *Black Slash ( \ ) *

Note: This black slash is added by CI.

Thanks

Comment: `$search = str_replace('\\', '', $search);`

Comment: did but still the same

Comment: So what happens when you try `$search = str_replace(" ","&#37;",$search);` instead of yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) states:

> Note: All values passed to this function are escaped automatically.

Basically, you can't pass a raw `"%"` to `->like()`. That said, you don't have full control over where the wildcards go; this comes close:

```
$this->db->like(['name' => 'Spinner', 'name' => '60'])
```

It would generate something like:

```
WHERE name LIKE '%Spinner%' AND name LIKE '%60%'
```